# The max of incoming, outgoing, or missed calls logs in Android

Tags: android

I am studying the The max of incoming, outgoing, or missed calls logs in Android.

I got the information from this website.

### https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/bypass-androids-call-log-limits-keep-unlimited-call-history-0175494/

By default, Android limits your call history to the last 500 incoming, outgoing, or missed calls. When you reach this limit, older entries get trimmed off the bottom of the list and deleted forever.

---

However, my colleague told me he have tried 1000 missed call in the Pixel phone.

Here is my question?

(1) What is the max of incoming, outgoing, or missed calls logs in Android?

(2) The limitations are the same between Android and Pixel phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, yes you're right, the limit of getting call logs is 500 entries only. But i guess this limit applies to the system android app only as it is the way Manufacturers develop it. Try installing other apps and you might get more than 500 entries.

Answer (score 0):

I extracted from my Redmi 9 Note Pro 9999 calls.